# webIDE Firefox OS simulator editor does not work

Tags: firefox-os

I am running firefox 38.0.5 on linux KDE (OpenMandriva 2014.1). When I open my firefox-os project under webIDE, I cannot edit its files. I can see the project directory structure on the left but when selecting a file (index.html for example) it is not opened in the editor panel. I keep on seeing the general description of the app. I cannot either navigate in the project subdirectory.

I have enabled the logging and this is the error I can see:

> A promise chain failed to handle a rejection. Did you forget to '.catch', or did you forget to 'return'?
>   See https://developer.mozilla.org/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Promise.jsm/Promise
>
> Date: Sun Jun 28 2015 12:03:54 GMT+0200 (CEST) Full Message: destroy
>   Full Stack: JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm ->
>   resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: PendingErrors.register :: line 162 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.completePromise :: line 675 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: Handler.prototype.process :: line 903 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop :: line 746 JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/Promise.jsm -> resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js :: this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/> :: line 688 native frame :: unknown filename :: TOP_LEVEL :: line 0

Only the webIDE editor is not working. The rest of the functionalities are working fine.

I have tried to open and edit with webIDE the same project with another computer (MS Windows) and it works perfectly.

Any hint would be welcome. Thank you!

**EDIT:** This problem will be fixed with Firefox 44.0. As sugested in [bugzilla bug 1208713](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208713) I have tested it successfully with the Firefox Nightly (44 at that time).

Comment: Have you tried to remove the IndexedDB file or cleaning your WebIDE profile?

Comment: @Cod1ngFree - I removed .mozilla/firefox/<my default profile>/storage/permanent/indexeddb+++fx-devtools, restarted firefox and webIDE but no change. I was not able to find my webIDE profile. Could you indicate the usual path?

Comment: That was the wbIDE profile :\ Maybe you should fill a bug in Bugzilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem will be fixed with Firefox 44.0. As sugested in [bugzilla bug 1208713](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1208713) I have tested it successfully with the Firefox Nightly (44 at that time).